# Access to a variable in the scope of a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I access a variable in the scope of a directive?

I have a directive like this:

```
angular.module('app').directive('any', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            attr: '@'
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.attr = $scope.attr != undefined;
        },
        template: 'Result (true/false): {{attr}}'
    };
});
```

And in the HTML, for example:

```
<any attr="bla"></any>
```

But the variable `$scope.attr` remains `bla`, does not change with the value of true or false. How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't use the same variable to hold the comparison with undefined and the actual `attr` value.

Every time angular executes its digest loop, it resets the new value of `attr` in the scope.

Comment: This is the correct answer for what you're looking for.  If you're expecting other behavior then please edit your question.

See here for a plunkr of this scenario to test this answer:  http://plnkr.co/edit/SHxBWN3eNDPUcacD6qaf?p=preview

Answer (score -1):

When you create an *isolate scope* in AngularJS, AngularJS provides 3 types of prefixes:

1. "@"   (  Text binding / one-way binding )
2. "="   ( Direct model binding / two-way binding )
3. "&"   ( Behaviour binding / Method binding  )

What you are using is the one-way binding method.  For you to use it in your HTML correctly, you need to do this:

```
<any attr="{{ bla }}"></any>
```

Comment: No, not if the goal is to pass the literal string "bla".